# username and password retrieval in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

As per Spring Security version 4, `j_username` and `j_password` are deprecated, and `username` and `password` should be used in JSP.

I see these variables are defined in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Can we override the properties through some external configuration so that it looks for `j_username`?

Comment: What does [tag:ldap] have to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default parameter names this way:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain formLoginFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            ...
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                    .usernameParameter("j_username")
                    .passwordParameter("j_password")
            );
    return http.build();
}
```

This way Spring Security will look for these parameters in the HTTP request when performing authentication.